# iPhone app: getting data without a web API

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

I am attempting to create a simple iOS application, mostly for the learning process, but one which might also be useful to other botanists. The [California Native Plant Society](http://www.cnps.org/) has a new [Rare plant database](http://www.rareplants.cnps.org/) online.  At first I would like to just do simple querys for a plant by name.  Later adding some type of location search, finding known occurrences of rare plants in your specific area.

So a search for `Layia' brings us to a [page](http://www.rareplants.cnps.org/result.html?fulldata=Layia) with a table.  Looking at the source for the page I believe the table is generated by:

```
<div class="breadcrumb top20">
<div class="line1 center">
<!--    <a href="/advanced.html" class="ret_search">Modify Search Criteria</a> -->
<span id=modifyCriteriaSlot></span>
&nbsp;
<span id=exportPdfSlot></span>
&nbsp;
<span id=exportExcelSlot></span>
&nbsp;
<!-- END line1 -->

<span id=modifyColumnsSlot></span>
&nbsp;
<span id=sortSlot></span>
&nbsp;
<span id=displayPhotosSlot></span>
</div>
<!-- END line1 -->
</div>
```

I guess I am stuck.  As far as the app goes I have been playing around with ASIHttpRequest and I see references to XMLKiss to parse web pages, but I just don't see any data on this page TO parse, it seems to be generated else ware and then just appears?  I know I am a little out of my element here, but I want to put in the time and learn what I need to, so a little direction would be an awesome help!  Thanks.

Comment: And if anyone is interested, I'll be putting this on githib...when there is something to actually put up there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it helps, they are showing the results table with this DIV

```
<div id=resultListSlot align=center style="max-width: 960px;"></div>
```

The DIV is being populated with javascript. The JS can be found here:

http://www.rareplants.cnps.org/org.cnps.Result/org.cnps.Result.nocache.js

Im not sure how you can get that to reply to your own request... let me look at it when I get back later today to see if I can help even more.

**--------- Update -----------**

If you wanted to skip learning JS you could just use firefox to view the DOM source which will include all the HTML generated by the JS. I just did a search for ALL of their plants, CTRL+A to select all of the page, right click on a highlighted area and "view selection source".

Then you could host your own page like I have done. Look at this page here http://luistovar.com/plants.html

Now you have all the plants, the HTML, the links and everything you need to create your own list. The only downfall is you would have to update every few weeks?? or so. It all depends on how often their data changes, or how much an updated list matters to you.
Might be better than learning JS though.

Comment: Great, I will look at this as well.  Just from a learning perspective (and at the risk of asking a silly question)... how exactly did you pin down that, that particular javascript was being called to generate the table?

Comment: I followed the HTML to that DIV block and noticed the description. It pretty much gives it away thats where the List is in. With nothing being populated in the DIV, I had a feeling it would be populated from JS (from previous experiences). So I disabled javascript on my browser with this tool: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/  . And when I did that, the LIST and most of the site disappeared. So then I looked at the source code and there is only 1 JS link. When you get into that applet and read a little, its clear thats where the list is coming from.

Comment: Well I still haven't figured this out, but you set me on a path to learning JS.  Perhaps after a little study I can figure out how exactly to solve this problem.

Comment: I think that would be a reasonable solution, and something I might look into.  But, in the interest in this being a standalone mobile application (not dependent on hosting an identical html list elseware), I think It would be worthwhile to learn enough JavaScript to understand how exactly the table is being populated and then trying to tie into that existing JS (if something like that is even possible? I have no idea.)  Thanks again for your help, You have answered many of my questions and perked up a number of new interests.